# You owe me Giri - what do I owe you?

Tags: words

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giri_(Japanese)) defines 義理 *giri* as

> a Japanese value roughly corresponding to "duty", "obligation", or even "burden of obligation". It is defined as "to serve one's superiors with a self-sacrificing devotion" by Namiko Abe.

Question: I have forgotten the inverse/reciprocal. What is the Japanese word for "duty" or "obligation" to those who owe you *giri*?

---

[Update] It seems like I maybe used the wrong word, or that others are misunderstanding me.

I am thinking of a novel I read about 20 years ago about mediaeval Japan.

Would it be correct to say that a samurai owes his lord giri? If not, what is the word? And, what duty of care/protection, etc, does the lord owe to the samurai?

Comment: >Question: I have forgotten the inverse/reciprocal. What is the Japanese word for duty or obligation to those who owe you Gri? I can't make out what you are trying to ask by this question.
Do your mean a word that means what merits for or earns someone's 義理?
Then they are things like 恩、給料、封土、利権、etc.

Comment: Apologies if I was not clear. Giri goes "upwards" - what goes "downwards"?

Comment: You mean a word that means "to serve one's *inferiors* with a self-sacrificing devotion"? The definition you quoted is simply crappy. The 義理 goes both ways. You can say you owe 義理 when your subordinate have helped you in some way.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not read kanji (and maybe I should not have chosen a definition form Wikipedia :-) . I mean that if I have a duty to serve my master, he also has a reciprocal duty to care for/protect me. What is that called?

Comment: This is not necessarily an answer (hence why it's in the comments), but 義理 seems to define the reciprocal relations. For instance, the company doesn't sack employees left, right and centre by prioritising profit over the employees; but in return, the employees go above and beyond to serve the company. 義理 seems to be the word that defines that obligation (both ways). I could be wrong. But that's what my reading has led me to conclude so far.

Comment: @someone Perhaps you could put in the furigana for Mawg's benefit. Mawg, In the meantime, I strongly recommend Rikaichan in firefox or Rikaikun in chrome (if you have those browsers) to read kanji, if reading Japanese is of interest to you :-)

Comment: @Robert Thanks for that (+1). As I said in a comment to a now deleted answer 1) sorry, but I don't read kanji, 2) I should probably not have quoted Wikipedia :-) That's where I copy/pasted the kanji from. My question is - I owe Giri to my boss/master/etc - what does he owe me in return? Care/protection/etc?  I know that there is a single Japanese word expressing this, but I have forgotten it

Comment: @Mawg The definition you quoted sounds more like 忠義(chuugi) or 奉公(houkou), or fealty. As I said giri is more like "a morally obligatory repayment to what you owe." As for the word what you are asking, I don't know. Is there English or Chinese word for it? But as I said usually fealty is rewarded by feud or something like that.

Comment: Please forget the deification form Wikimedia - my bad. To try again (and maybe I nmisunerstand Giri) - I think* that Giri is something that I owe to you, my lord, mater, boss, etc BUT, it is not a one way street; you owe me something is return (I think that the word begins with O, but am not sure). Hmm, if I am wrong about the definition of Giri, what is the word for "obligation upwards"? And what is the reciprocal?

Comment: I googled and came across one word that seems to fit your bill  御恩(goh-on). But it's Kamakura-era word that means the obligatory rewards to 御家人(gokeninn: kamakura-era lessor lords)'s services done and it's not a modern word by any means.

Comment: There is another word 恩 (おん; on). That is equivalent to social debt. The debt cannot be fully repaid. If you go beyond what is ordinary to help someone, this can incur 恩. 恩 binds you to the other person. I'm not sure how this is related to 義理, since 義理 is closer to the word 'obligation'. For instance, women give 義理チョコ girichoko (giri chocolate) to their male coworkers on valentines day. This, I don't think, doesn't come from social debt. 本命 (honmei) is different. That is from genuine feeling.

Comment: @someone I don't mind it not being modern. I am thinking of a word that I read about 20 years ago in a novel about feudal Japan. Does your word mean that the one owed Giri has a duty to care for & protect, etc, the one who owes him giri?

Comment: @Mawg, I think that is roughly correct. The 先輩/後輩 (senpai/kouhai) works the same way. Roughly translated as: Senior/junior. Of course, there is 義理. The senior has an obligation to help and protect the 後輩. On the other hand, the 後輩 has inferior rank, so they have a duty to serve the 先輩 in some capacity, for instance carrying out favours. This relationship is much stronger in Japan than in the West.

Comment: That sounds good. Please post it as an answer (but please be sure that it is not necessary to read kanji to understand it :-)   +1   Btw, it is very similar to the old Roman relationship towards one's clientes (plus ca change ...).

Comment: Yes, it's roughly the same. I used to be a Roman history reading buff. I'm not sure the two societies work in quite the same way. I think the Roman (upper class) were more concerned with public duty than the complex web of obligation that exists in Japanese society. Also, I think their notion of honour and duty is somewhat different. Romans seemed to be more individualistic and, if my reading is any guide, opportunistic. I can't imagine Cicero in Japan.

Comment: @Mawg,  It's Kamakura-era word and I don't know it was still in use in the later eras (I mean Muromachi and Edo eras) . And yes goh-on is rewarded to houkou(services derived from the fealty) and they are reciprocal duties of a kind of "contract."

Comment: I 100% agree. All upper class Romans were for themselves first. Many were also for Rome, more did not care & were only for themselves. Only a few, like that @#$%!  Cato (the younger (great grandson of Cato the Censor, though his slave)) seemed to only for the state. If you think that "giri" captures one side of the Roam client relationship, then please post your answer with the reciprocal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the questioner's request, I'm putting my response here:

義理 defines a reciprocal obligation. For example, a company looks after its workers, and in return the latter demonstrate their loyalty beyond the ordinary. 義理チョコ(girichoko) is another example of duty, in this case motivating a female employee's giving her male co-workers chocolate on Valentines Day, as is the custom. If she gives chocolate to someone she has genuine feelings for, this gift is 本命チョコ(honmeichoko). This present isn't simply an expression of duty.

先輩/後輩(senpai/kouhai) is another example of duty that exists on both the side of the senior 先輩 and junior 後輩. The 先輩 gives protection and helps the 後輩, while the 後輩 serves the 後輩 in some capacity, in keeping with their inferior status.

I think the concept you were reaching for in your question is 恩(on). This is roughly equivalent to a social debt. It is not necessarily an automatic expression of duty. This comes when someone goes a step further to help someone. In return, the person receiving the benefit feels a debt of gratitude, which can never be repaid, so they are bound to their benefactor. There is a complex web of 恩.